# How do I search for ü using the search api

Tags: sharepoint-search, search-api, special-characters

I have been trying to search for ü in the title field of documents using the search api. It doesn't return any results.

https://mysite.domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title:"*ü*"'&sourceid='95A59305-0FD1-41E2-8C84-6EDB47EB8944'&selectproperties='Location,LegalDocumentType,LegalContractingPartyIssuer,LegalFileRef,LegalMartinsParty,LegalDepartments,LegalSubCategory,LegalRouteWarehouseNumber'

Any ideas on how to search for a special character?

Comment: Does it not work to simply pass the URL encoded version of that character `%C3%BC` as in `https://mysite.domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title:%C3%BC'&sourceid='95A59305-0FD1-41E2-8C84-6EDB47EB8944'&selectproperties='Location,LegalDocumentType,LegalContractingPartyIssuer,LegalFileRef,LegalMartinsParty,LegalDepartments,LegalSubCategory,LegalRouteWarehouseNumber'` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It still doesn't return anything. Evening using the built-in search screens it doesn't return properly for ü. It seems to return everything with a u instead of ü.

Comment: I have another page that uses the standard rest api call (not the search api). The encoding does work on that page. So I was surprised when I couldn't get it to work with search. I'm wondering if it has something to do with how we have search setup. However, I need to use the search api because of how many items are in the list.